# Maximum consecutive repeats in a vector in R

Tags: r

I have a vector containing 0 and 1. I want to return the maximum value of number of times 1 appears consecutively.  For e.g. if x is the input vector

```
 x <-c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
```

Expected Output: 3

My attempt: 
I'm using function rle to do this job. Here is my sample code:

```
x<-c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
y<-rle(x)
max_repeat <-max(y$lengths)
```

In this scenario, I get output as 4 (corresponding to 0 instead of 1). I tried to use tapply to access the complete output of rle, but I am not able to extract out the maximum repeat corresponding to value 1.

```
out <-tapply(y$lengths, y$values, max)
```

This is what I get for out:

```
0 1
4 3
```

When I look at the structure of out, it is " int [1:2(1d)] 4 3". I do not have enough experience with dealing this type of variables. I need to extract the value corresponding to 1 i.e. 3. Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You're, almost, there: `out[["1"]]` or `max(y$lengths[y$values == 1])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
x<-c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
y<-rle(x)
max(y$lengths[y$values==1])
# 3
```

If you want informations about any object, here **y** you can use the function **str**, which will return informations about what contains any object.

Answer (score 1):

I found it like this =>

```
x <-c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
y=rle(x)
max(y$lengths[y$values==1])
```

hope it meets your expectations.

Comment: This is exactly the same as the other answer.

Comment: realised it now, i saw the question and set about working on it.. when i hit submit, it came back and told me that there is another answer... works out to be same..